как добавить модуль snmp в apache24 чтобы работали запросы на коммутатор? Не нашел ничего на ОС windows 10
как добавить модуль snmp в apache24, чтобы работали запросы на коммутатор? Не нашел ничего на ОС windows 10
snmp вроде как установил, но апаче все равно не видит.

Что-то как-то ничего не понятно, в чём связь между snmp, apache24 и коммутатором и зачем тут вообще апач? Что-то мешает отправлять «запросы на коммутатор» без использования апача или в чём суть?

Или вы имеете в виду, что хотите отправлять snmp-запросы из php-скрипта, но почему-то решили ограничиться лишь упоминанием его в метке?

у меня сайт, где надо делать запрос SNMP этот сайт стоит на апаче. данные в phpmyadmin и у меня не видит апаче snmp

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
